# Remote desktop applications slow down after a while

Tags: networking, 22.04, remote-desktop

I have a remote PC running Ubuntu 22.04. It's an unattended machine with a fast and stable ADSL connection and I have a couple of remote desktop applications to connect: AnyDesk and TeamViewer, but I've tried for a while UltraVNC too. The local machine runs 22.04 as well (but I tried with 23.04 too).

After a couple of hours from power on, the remote desktop connection slows down to a refresh per second or less, making it almost unusable. Rebooting the system restore the normal behavior for few other hours, then it happens again.

- It does *not* depend from the application: it happens with AnyDesk and TeamViewer.
- It does *not* depend from the Internet connection: both the local and remote machine have a quite fast ADSL connection (about 60 Mbits download and 30-40 Mbits upload).
- It does *not* depend from the CPU usage, it happens even with no applications running
- It does *not* depend from the RAM usage, when it happen there's still a lot of free memory:

```
    $ free -h
                   total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:           7.6Gi       1.7Gi       3.8Gi       395Mi       2.1Gi       5.2Gi
    Swap:          4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

- It happens even if both local and remote machines are inside the same LAN

What else can I check to understand why it happens?